# Why do I get a warning when I delete my own post with only my comment in it?

Tags: support, deletion, deleted-questions, meta, post-ban

I asked a question 10 minutes ago, I added a comment for more info about the question with a comment. 2 minutes later I was able to solve the problem and wanted to delete my post. I got a warning which was mentioning about a "ban" if I keep deleting my posts with comments.

Is there a reason for this? Will I receive a ban if I delete posts with only my own comments?

Comment: If you delete a high proportion of your questions, you might run into a rate limiting. One thing, you wrote "comment" here, but it was posted as an answer (although it wasn't really an answer), and deleting questions with answers is not well-liked. The system doesn't check who posted the answer. If such a situation arises again, _first_ delete your answer, _then_ delete your question. That way, the system doesn't think you delete a question with a third party's answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you! It makes sense to delete my answer first.

Comment: Also, just because you answered your own question doesn't mean you should delete it.  It might be a useful example for someone else later on.  Answering your own questions is perfectly valid!